# Python 2 - How do I import a text file containing a long sequence of digits and convert it to a string of individual numbers?

Tags: python, import, text-files

I want to take a text file that is a long sequence of digits with line breaks,
i.e. something like

```
38482406847387
85869153438194
96531040384827
43157689643163
```

but much larger, and convert it to a string that would just read

```
[3,8,4,8,...,1,6,3]
```

so that I can iterate over it, manipulate it, visualise it and so on.

I have had a look at the `open()` function but so far I can only get it to break up the file into separate lines. I know I can use a `for` loop to go through the giant string of the whole document and form a list that way, but then I get '/n' and spaces showing up everywhere, which is undesirable.

For context, I grabbed a text file from the web of some preposterous number of digits of pi, and I thought it would be instructive and interesting to go through it and look for patterns, plot the distribution of digits, convert to ASCII and other such nonsense. I figured it would be a fun way for me to learn a bit more about Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

print re.findall('\d', open('file.txt', 'r').read())
```

Comment: Probably slower than a non-regex solution, and the file should be opened with a `with`.

Comment: @user2357112 makes sense, but I don't really think speed is one of Rife168's concerns. I prefer code readability over performance when the latter is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For small files:

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = list(int(i) for i in ''.join(line.strip() for line in infile))
```

For larger files:

```
answer = []
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        answer.extend([int(i) for i in line.strip()])
```

Comment: You forgot to loop over the file in the second one.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think you could add a few sentences explaining briefly what you have done? I'm not sure I understand what 'with' means here, and why there would need to be different code for large and small files. If the second one is more efficient then couldn't you use that all the time?

Comment: Your first answer blows up for me.  Are you sure you don't want:  `answer = list(int(i) for line in infile for i in ''.join(line.strip()))`??

Answer (score 0):

If you get all the numbers as a string then you can use

```
# here, digits is the numbers as a string including the \n character
list = [digit for digit in digits.replace('\n', '')]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the 'replace' method, it will be useful here. If I wanted to get rid of both spaces and '/n' then could I do that in one step or would I need to replace one thing then the other?

Comment: @Rife168 you could do `list = [digit for digit in digits.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')]` although that looks very hack-y.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("/path/to/file") as f:
    print [int(x) for x in f.read() if x.isdigit()]
```

This is shorter.